# Global array declaration in C?

Tags: c, data-structures

I need to declare an array globally, because I want all methods to be able to access it in the main.c program. However, if I declare it in main.h, I will have to give it a size at declaration time - the problem is, I don't know the size until InitializeMemory(...) method is called, which takes user input to be the size of the array.

Comment: Why do you have to use a global? Why not encapsulate?

Comment: I agree - for pointers and such, you should provide an `int *array(void)` function that returns a pointer to the array (and perhaps another function to get the array's current size) so that no one uses it inappropriately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create it like `int *ptr;` globally (let say it's integer);
then in your function;

```
 ptr = (int *) malloc(100*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: In C, I wouldn't cast. I'd use `array = malloc(100 * sizeof *array);`

Answer (score 3):

Don't make it a global array, make it a **global pointer** (to a heap-allocated array), and have it initialized appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to allocate a global array at with the size only known at runtime, then you want to just a pointer and then you'll malloc in your code once you know the size.

```
 int *array;
 ...
 array = malloc(size_from_initialize_memory_function);
 // check that array != NULL.
```

Comment: No, he can. With C99 VLA he doesn't know the size at compile time.

Comment: Sure, but I didn't see a C99 tag ;-)

Comment: VLAs can only be defined at block scope.  Oh, and don't cast the result of `malloc()`.